# Spring 3 Annotations - HibernateDaoSupport - Repository Requires Session Factory

Tags: hibernate, spring, annotations, autowired

I am getting an exception saying :

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException:
>   'sessionFactory' or
>   'hibernateTemplate' is required

When trying to use the `@Repository` annotation on a HibernateDaoSupport class.  The error message is straightforward, in order to create the Repository it needs a sessionFactory.  However,I have defined a session factory in my XML:

```
<!-- Hibernate -->
    <bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dashDataSource" />
        <property name="annotatedClasses">
            <list>
                <value>com.mycomp.myapp.Category</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

So I'm not sure how to give the repository the SessionFactory that it requires while it's creating it's annotation driven beans, I attempted to do the following:

```
 @Autowired
    protected HibernateTemplate createHibernateTemplate(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        return super.createHibernateTemplate(sessionFactory);
    }
```

But this does not solve the problem, likely because the repository needs that property while instantiating, not just when performing an action.  Unfortunately, I don't know how to get around this problem because there are no constructors or initialization methods to override with a @Autowired annotation.

I checked to make sure the sessionFactory bean is being created and can be Autowired, and that is fine.

Comment: You may not want to use Hibernatetemplate anymore as it does not offer much benefit http://blog.springsource.org/2007/06/26/so-should-you-still-use-springs-hibernatetemplate-andor-jpatemplate/

Answer (score 36, accepted):

`HibernateDaoSupport` is supplied with `SessionFactory` via `setSessionFactory()`. However, `setSessionFactory()` is `final`, so you can't override it to add an `@Autowired` annotation. But you can apply `@Autowired` to the arbitrary method and call `setSessionFactory()` from it:

```
@Autowired
public void init(SessionFactory factory) {
    setSessionFactory(factory);
}
```

Comment: awesome, thanks!  I already started to go down the route of using the session factory directly, but was struggling to open transactions, I think I will just go with the DAOSupport though, as it works great for my simple purposes.

Answer (score 6):

You can also define which session factory you want to use (if you have more than one, for instance), by using the `@Qualifier` annotation:

```
@Autowired
public MyClassImpl(@Qualifier("myOtherSessionFactory") SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);
}
```

You can also toggle between data sources by extending the `AbstractRoutingDataSource`.  See [this page](http://blog.springsource.com/2007/01/23/dynamic-datasource-routing/).

Comment: atrain@ If we separate data sources, do we need to create separate sessionFactories ? if yes, Can you please give an example how to  use (inject) two different session Factories  in the DAO implementation ( which implements HibernateDaoSupport )