# "Property 'sessionFactory' is required" in Spring?

Tags: hibernate, spring, sessionfactory

I have a problem with sessionFactory in Spring.

```
public abstract class GenericDao<T,PK extends Serializable>
extends HibernateDaoSupport 
implements IGenericDao<T, Serializable> {

private Class<T> persistentClass;

public Class<T> getPersistentClass() {
    return persistentClass;
}

public void setPersistentClass(Class<T> persistentClass) {
    this.persistentClass = persistentClass;
}
```

---

```
@Repository
@Transactional
public class CategoryDao extends GenericDao<Category, Long> {
@Autowired
private SessionFactory sessionFactory;
public CategoryDao() {
    setPersistentClass(Category.class);
    setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

}
```

---

And My sessionFactoryBean defined in appContext.xml file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@Autowired` works after object is constructed, thus you cannot use its result in a constructor.

You can use [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230608/spring-3-annotations-hibernatedaosupport-repository-requires-session-factory/3230867#3230867) to autowire `SessionFactory` into `HibernateDaoSupport`.

Answer (score 1):

You need this line in your appContext.xml:

```
<context:annotation-config/>
```

Here's a full example: http://blog.springsource.com/2007/05/14/annotation-driven-dependency-injection-in-spring-21/