# Hibernate, Spring, Dao getSession() NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I get the error.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport.getSession(HibernateDaoSupport.java:143)
at com.walladverts.model.dao.UserDao.findByUsername(UserDao.java:25)
```

while accessing getSession() in findByUsername

```
package com.walladverts.model.dao;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import com.walladverts.exceptions.DataNotFoundException;
import com.walladverts.model.entities.User;
import com.walladverts.util.CustomHibernateDaoSupport;@
Repository("userDao")
public class UserDao extends CustomHibernateDaoSupport {
    public void save(User user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().save(user);
    }
    public void delete(User user) {
        getHibernateTemplate().delete(user);
    }
    public User findByUsername(String username) throws DataNotFoundException {
        Session session = getSession();
        Criteria crit = session.createCriteria(User.class);
        System.out.println(username);
        crit.add(Restrictions.eq("username", username));
        crit.setMaxResults(1);
        List < User > users = crit.list();
        System.out.println(users);
        if (users.size() < 1) {
            throw new DataNotFoundException();
        }
        return users.get(0);
    }
}
```

Parent class:

```
package com.walladverts.util;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.support.HibernateDaoSupport;
public abstract class CustomHibernateDaoSupport extends HibernateDaoSupport {@
    Autowired
    public void init(SessionFactory factory) {
        setSessionFactory(factory);
    }
}
```

**Does anybody has an idea why this occurs? It freezes me for developing.**

EDIT:

It happens when Spring Secure tries to sign in an user. Also my SessionFactory is working OK when calling this method from Controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public abstract class CustomHibernateDaoSupport extends HibernateDaoSupport {
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("sessionFactory")
    private SessionFactory sessionFactory；

    public Session getSession() {
        return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
    }
}
```

---

```
public User findByUsername(String username) throws DataNotFoundException {
     Session session = getSession();
     // do sth
}
```

Comment: I cannot override it, it is a final method from HibernateDaoSupport.

Comment: Have you defined a bean named sessionFactory?

Comment: I guess this wrong answer was accepted by OP only to increase acceptance rate.

Answer (score 0):

`HibernateDaoSupport` for a very long time has final [getSessionFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/springframework/spring/1.2.4/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.java#89) and [setSessionFactory](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/springframework/spring/1.2.4/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.java#69) methods that can't be overriden.

It was initially supposed to mitigate xml configuration via `<property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory" />` but mixing it `@Autowired` annotation is [also possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230608/spring-3-annotations-hibernatedaosupport-repository-requires-session-factory/3230867#3230867).

The you would have to just call [getSession()](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/support/HibernateDaoSupport.html#getSession--) method when needed.